# How could i create generalized library to create database related functionality

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, class-library

Every time when i create a new application i need to create library for the application with relative tables to handle database related functionality. For ex. lets say i am creating application for a shopping mall them my library will have functionality having business objects based on need. Now if i am creating another project for vessel management then i need to create another library with specific business objects.

Is there a way i could create my framework to handle DB related functionality with custom business objects i could pass to it.

OR any suggestions on how to create my custom framework that could easily manage database related functionality.

Thanks for sharing your wisdom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should take a look ah [nhibernate](/questions/tagged/nhibernate) and [entity-framework](/questions/tagged/entity-framework) and similar frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of many existing [Object-Relational Mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-Relational_Mapping) frameworks, for example [Entity Framework](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework)